# silly mistake o' mine: hibernate SQL throwing invalid character

Tags: java, hibernate, concatenation

### Disclaimer: This was just a silly mistake i made. Did not close it because maybe some other person did the same thing and might find it useful.

two tables:

```
COR_RADICADO_OFICIO:
- num_radicado (pk)
- ano_radicado (pk)
```

(I know, composite pks are evil but it's a legacy db, not my design ;) )

and

```
COR_RESPUESTA_OFICIO:
- num_radicado (text)(fk)
- ano_radicado (number)(fk)
- requiere_respuesta (number)
```

In hibernate:

```
createSQLQuery("select * from COR_RADICADO_OFICIO where REQUIERE_RESPUESTA = 399 " +
"and concat(concat(num_radicado , '_'),  ano_radicado) not  in "+ 
"(select concat(concat(num_radicado , '_), ano_radicado) from COR_RESPUESTA_OFICIO);" );
```

if i execute this query directly on oracle, it works fine, however hibernate throws

```
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00911: invalid character
```

Tried replacing 'concat' function with '||' and got the same error.

Any ideas how to fix that one? (besides creating a view).

Comment: `concat(num_radicado , '_)` - typo?

Comment: Why do you think "*composite PKs are evil*". They are perfectly valid.

Comment: yes, it is actually a typing error

Comment: to mr horse: in my experience, composite pks are a pain in the rear because of two reasons: first, as your model evolves is very likely that the fields that you had as pks change. second, whenever you handle subqueries you have to do ugly tricks as concatenation, like in the query depicted in my question that can affect badly performance and turn your queries hard to read and debug.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try removing the semicolon maybe?
The error you are getting doesn't say invalid SQL, it says invalid character which is something different altogether.

Comment: yup, that was just a typo, the real problem was the semicolon.